# Ho can i run a powershell comand from a .ps1 file?

Tags: azure, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I have the following:

```
$command = "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
$arguments = @('Set-AzLogicApp -ResourceGroupName "MyResourceGroup" -Name "MyLogicAppName" -State "Disabled" -Force')
& $command $arguments
```

when I run this from command it says `Set-AzLogicApp : The term 'Set-AzLogicApp' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet`

Any reason why this is ?

Comment: that type of error msg usually means the module that holds the cmdlet is not loaded. have you tested to see if the cmdlet is loaded in that situation?

Comment: Check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/About/about_PowerShell_exe?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: Yes i have , i ran Get-Command -Verb * -Noun Az* | Select-Object -Property Name and it returned it .

Comment: Try to run `Import-Module -Name "Az.LogicApp"` before running the `Set-AzLogicApp`.

Comment: I thought it worked by running , Install-Module -Name Az but no difference.

Comment: I said `Import-Module` not `Install-Module`, could you have a try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to understand why are you calling Powershell.exe from .ps1 file. Anyway all the installed module will be available for execution if you are executing PS file. You can just simply import the module and run the command.

Additionally , you have to  import Az.LogicApp as Joy mentioned after installing it in the machine.

Code would look like below:

```
Import-Module -Name "Az.LogicApp"
$command = "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
$arguments = @('Set-AzLogicApp -ResourceGroupName "MyResourceGroup" -Name "MyLogicAppName" -State "Disabled" -Force')
& $command $arguments
```

[image]

I have tried at my end and it worked for me. Please try and let me know if you need any further assistance.

Comment: I am running the above , I am calling it from my c# app from command . I have installed powershell and the modules,  From Powershell IDE I can run correctly no problem  , but from my app when I run tell to run a commad I get the following error:     Import-Module : The specified module 'Az.LogicApp' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module 
directory.

Comment: Check this and see if it helps else let me know will take a look. https://serverfault.com/questions/568257/import-module-azure-fails

Comment: I have looked at the link , I don't cant seem to locate any of those directories :\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\PowerShell etc . I think if I can run the following form a cmd prompt , C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe Set-AzLogicApp -ResourceGroupName "myresourcegroupname" -Name "mylogicappname" -State "Disabled" -Force, then I should be able to run it from my c# app or even my Jenkins server. I ran az webapp commands in Jenkins without any problem and also I run the az login as a batch command from Jenkins . But I cant seem to run Set-AzLogicApp.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted , I had to run Install-Module -Name Az . thanks for all the help